# Merging rasterstacks with different dimensions/projections

Tags: r, gis, raster

How can I extract the whole CONUS SSURGO data from `FedData` and then how can I combine that rasterstack into a single rasterstack with `worldclim` data?

```
# FedData Tester
library(FedData)
library(magrittr)

# Extract data for the Village Ecodynamics Project "VEPIIN" study area:
# http://veparchaeology.org
vepPolygon <- polygon_from_extent(raster::extent(672800, 740000, 4102000, 4170000),
                                  proj4string = "+proj=utm +datum=NAD83 +zone=12")

# Get the NRCS SSURGO data (USA ONLY)
SSURGO.VEPIIN <- get_ssurgo(template = vepPolygon, 
                     label = "VEPIIN")
# Plot the NED again
raster::plot(NED)
# Plot the SSURGO mapunit polygons
plot(SSURGO.VEPIIN$spatial,
     lwd = 0.1,
     add = TRUE)
```

...

```
library(raster)
library(sp)

r <- getData("worldclim",var="bio",res=2.5)
```

Comment: you need to get to a common projection and a common resolution

Comment: A great place to learn how to do these kinds of geospatial operations in R is here: https://www.rspatial.org/ .  Figure out how to make a coding attempt and then reframe your question around a sample dataset and your non-working code, following the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example